# Elements of the method of forcing in some papers of N. N. Luzin

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, ho.history-overview, forcing

In the paper

> [Eléments de la méthode de forcing dans quelques travaux de N. N. Lousin](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-8599-7_22). (French) [Elements of the method of forcing in some papers of N. N. Luzin] Amphora, 469–479, Birkhäuser, Basel, 1992.

Fedor Medvedev has claimed the following:

> P. Cohen, who proved the independence of the axiom of choice and of the generalized continuum hypothesis by the method of forcing, did not invent this method, but discovered it in the works of his predecessors. The aim of the paper is to indicate some elements of the method in the works of N. N. Luzin.

I could find the paper, but it is in French, and so I  could not read it.

**Does anyone know how the work of Luzin is related to forcing?**

The following papers of Luzin are mentioned in the above paper:

1) LOUZIN, N.: Sur un probleme de M. Baire. Comptes
rend. de l'Acad. sei. de Paris 158 (1914),1258-
1261. - LOUZIN, N. N.: Sur une theoreme de
Baire. ffiuvres completes. Moscou: Mit. Acad. des
Seiences de l'U.R.S.S., v. 11, 1958, pp. 683-685.

2) LOUZINE, N.: Sur l'existance d'un ensemble nondenombrable
qui est de premiere categorie sur tout
ensemble parfait. Fund. Math. 2 (1921), 155-157.
- LOUZINE, N. N.: Sur l'existance de l'ensemble
de premiere categorie dans tout ensemble parfait.
ffiuvres completes. Moscou: Mit. Acad. des Seiences
de l'U.R.S.S., v. 11, 1958, pp. 692-694.

3) LOUZINE, N.: Sur une question concemant la propriete
de Baire. Fund. Math. 9 (1927), 116-118.-LOUZINE, N. N.: Sur un point, concernant la propriete
de Baire.

4) LOUZINE, N.: Sur les ensembles toujours de premiere
categorie. Fund. Math. 21 (1933), 114-126.
- LOUZINE, N. N.: Sur les ensembles toujours de
la premiere categorie.

5) LOUZINE, N., SERPINSKI, W.: Sur un ensemble
non-denombrable qui est de premiere categorie sur
tout ensemble parfait. Atti della R. Acad. dei LinceL
Serie 6. 7 (1928), 214-215. - LOUZINE, N.
N., SERPINSKI, W.: Sur l'ensemble denombrable,
etant l'ensemble de premiere categorie sur tout ensemble
parfait.

**Are there any English translation of the above papers of Luzin?**

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the following papers will be helpful:

http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/29/5/A04/ (The ideas of N. N. Luzin in descriptive set theory, by L. V. Keldysh)

http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/40/3/R06/ (Luzin's contribution to the descriptive theory of sets and functions: concepts, problems, predictions, 
by V.A. Uspenskii)